# How can I increase the width of ng-dropdown-multiselect created using bootstrap AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-dropdown-multiselect

I have created a multi select dropdown using AngularJS and bootstrap and in the pages I include the following code:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <label>Standards</label>
                        <ng-dropdown-multiselect
                                options="dashboard.example1data"
                                selected-model="dashboard.example1model"
                        style="max-width: 500px;">
                        </ng-dropdown-multiselect>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am trying to increase the width of the dropdown and I am not sure how I can achieve that. Could someone let me know how we can increase the width of "ng-dropdown-multiselect".

Comment: <ng-dropdown-multiselect class="wide"> ...

And add a css style to override that style setting wrong width

Comment: @Vitalii Could you be little more elaborate please. What css style do I need to add.

Comment: `ng-dropdown-multiselect{ width:300px;}` is this you want? @Valla add this to you style tag or css file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to override the CSS which is used to make the button with drop down.

Put the below CSS either inside the `<script></script>` or in some external CSS file which gets loaded before your html file.

```
.multiselect-parent .dropdown-toggle {
  width: 400px;
}

.multiselect-parent .dropdown-menu {
  width: 300px;
}
```

This would solve your issue.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

This CSS works for me:

```css
.multiselect-parent {
  width: 100%;
}

.multiselect-parent .dropdown-toggle {
  width: 100%;
}

.multiselect-parent .dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything instead you just have to increase

> itemsShowLimit

Property value like

```
 this.dropdownSettings = {
    singleSelection: false,
    idField: 'item_id',
    textField: 'item_text',
    selectAllText: 'Select All',
    unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
    itemsShowLimit: 100,
    allowSearchFilter: true
  };
```